# Error 404 being given on a virtaul host with custom .htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, apache2, vhosts

I have an apache2 installation on my local linux server. It has a virtual host called `pcts.local` which has the root `/var/www/repos/pcts/`. Inside the root of pcts.local is a .htaccess file which attempts to rewrite urls to include .php if it isn't given like below:

```
http://pcts.local/ -> http://pcts.local/index.php
http://pcts.local/contact -> http://pcts.local/contact.php
```

The problem is, `http://pcts.local/contact` gives an error 404 but `http://pcts.local/contact.php` gives 200.

#### Virtual Host Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName pcts.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/repos/pcts

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

#### .htaccess file in `/var/www/repos/pcts/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance of any help!

Comment: Is that your complete VirtualHost config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName pcts.local
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/repos/pcts
>
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

If this is your complete config then your `.htaccess` file is not being processed.

You've not enabled `.htaccess` overrides for the specific directory. (ie. You've not enabled the parsing of `.htaccess` files.) `.htaccess` overrides are disabled by default.

However, you've not enabled access to this area of the filesystem either? Have you done this elsewhere in the server config?!

You should have a relevant `<Directory>` section like the following *inside* the `<VirtualHost>` container:

```
<Directory /var/www/repos/pcts>
    # Enable .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All

    # Allow user access to this directory
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You can restrict `.htaccess` overrides further if required (see the reference link below)

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Thank you, I think this has solved the issue because now I'm getting an error 500 (internal server error) which is probably due to the PHP file itself.

Comment: @CobainAmbrose Have you enabled/installed mod_rewrite? This is an additional Apache module, not installed by default. If mod_rewrite is not installed then you will also get a 500 error. Check the web server's error log for the details of the error.

Comment: Thanks for this, the module was not enabled and now the 500 error fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, REQUEST_FILENAME is expecting a file with a php extension to perform the rewrite.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried this just now but I'm still getting a 404 I'm afraid.

Comment: "REQUEST_FILENAME is expecting a file with a php extension" - That doesn't really make sense. Changing the second condition to `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is redundant since the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ `^([^\.]+)$` is very unlikely to match a file anyway. The OPs original condition is "OK" since it's testing whether the `.php` file exists before rewriting the request.